# Can i have 2 skeleton in one mesh? Three.js

Tags: three.js

Can i have 2 skeleton in one mesh? I haven't seen anything like that so i'm confuse if that's feasible or not.

[This is what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urQ4t.png)

As you can see in the image I already have one skeleton in the right side of the plane mesh. Now I want to put another skeleton to the left side so I can animate it in the way that I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple bones in a skeleton. You shouldn't need multiple skeletons, and I doubt multiple skeletons on a single mesh is supported.